# django admin - select user objects per each row - low performances

Tags: python, django

I have model that includes user object as foreign key.
While I present it on Django admin, it selects all the users objects per each row of the model (it shows them within dropdown).

How can I make just one select of user objects and then use it for all of the rows?

Queries:

```
SELECT ••• FROM "users_user" ORDER BY "users_user"."email" ASC
SELECT ••• FROM "users_user" ORDER BY "users_user"."email" ASC
SELECT ••• FROM "users_user" ORDER BY "users_user"."email" ASC
SELECT ••• FROM "users_user" ORDER BY "users_user"."email" ASC
SELECT ••• FROM "users_user" ORDER BY "users_user"."email" ASC
SELECT ••• FROM "users_user" ORDER BY "users_user"."email" ASC
SELECT ••• FROM "users_user" ORDER BY "users_user"."email" ASC
SELECT ••• FROM "users_user" ORDER BY "users_user"."email" ASC
SELECT ••• FROM "users_user" ORDER BY "users_user"."email" ASC
```

My admin-model:

```
class RoleAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Role
    fields = ('user', 'role_type', 'is_active',)
    extra = 0
```

*Edit:

I've tried to add the following code but it doesn't make sense:

```
def queryset(self, request):
    return super(RoleAdmin, self).queryset(request).select_related('user')
```

*Update:

I tried to set raw_ids_fields but it's still ineffective because it doesn't make inner join between roles and users but queries per each user separately.

Answer (score 1):

Django `InlineModelAdmin`(Super class of [`TabularInline`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline)) has an option called [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) which, instead of fetching all the records and showing a dropdown, shows a simple text field with all the IDs of the selected items and a button to browse and de/select records. E.g.

```
class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book
    raw_id_fields = ("pages",)
```

and it looks like this -

[image: raw_id_fields output]

Comment: It's still ineffective. It makes select query per each user instead of inner join between the roles and the users.

Comment: Please update your question with what you've tried and the output.